# Wrapping WCF client with Stream for disposing

Tags: c#, design-patterns, wcf, garbage-collection, decorator

I need to consume data from a WCF service, which pipes it through a stream. The data itself is contents of an archive file, so it needs additional logic, which I am splitting off into a separate class.

Now, normally, I would use a couple of nested  `using` statements, like so:

```
// Inside class that does the retrieval
using (var client = new FooWcfServiceClient(endpointName))
{
    // Some logic for specifying the request
    using (var dataStream = client.SomeMethod(request))
    {
        // Consuming logic goes here
    }
}
```

But I do not want my retrieval class from above to be dependent on the class that does the actual work on the `dataStream`.

But that means, that I need to somehow pass an open stream out of the method above, without closing the connection.

The solution I came up with is to simply make a decorator like this:

```
class DisposingStreamDecorator : Stream, IDisposable
```

and then simply pass both the client and the original stream into the decorator, to be disposed later inside `Dispose()`. At the same time all the other members, inherited from `Stream` are passed onto the stream it wraps.

Is this a bad design decision? Are there any issues I am not seeing?

Comment: I'm confused by your question. What problem do you see with passing `dataStream` to another method?

Comment: Also be aware of the dangers of `using` a wcf client: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573872/what-is-the-best-workaround-for-the-wcf-client-using-block-issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I do not want my retrieval class from above to be dependent on the class that does the actual work on the `dataStream`.

That's what abstractions are for. If you inject that dependency, then you avoid tightly coupling your code to that dependency. And you avoid the problem you are trying to work around of `Dispose` being called too early.

So your code might look something like:

```
void Foo(Action<Stream> consume)
{
    using (var client = new FooWcfServiceClient(endpointName))
    {
        // Some logic for specifying the request
        using (var dataStream = client.SomeMethod(request))
        {
            consume(dataStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Heagon, that depends on how you measure "better". To achieve this, you are having to fight the system's wish to call `Dispose` when the method exits. To me, that doesn't seem better than using the well established pattern of higher ordered functions (HOFs) as I'm doing here (ignoring the fact that I've used `void`, which means it's not strictly a HOF).